# Como manter tabelas sincronizadas em diferentes base de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sincronização, replicação

### Problema

Estou com um problema em que necessito realizar a sincronização de algumas tabelas de um banco de dados legado para outro banco de dados mais simples que será utilizado por um aplicativo externo.

### Tentativas

Então comecei a analisar técnicas manuais para realizar o gerenciamento das alterações em ambas as bases e replica-las nas outras (nem entrando no mérito de conflitos e *merge*).

Mas percebi que em algumas formas que pude modelar, elas acabam sendo propensas a falhas em alguns cenários, sem contar a quantidade de colunas extras só para fazer controle as versões e auditoria dos registros.

### Pergunta

Então acredito que tenha algumas abordagens, técnicas e modelagens de banco de dados que facilitem esse trabalho, e auxiliem na manutenção dos dados atualizados em ambas bases de dados, talvez até prevendo conflitos e *merge*.

Algo que possam me indicar? Algo que funcione de forma similar para me basear?

---

> Obs: A integração não pode ser realizada através do banco da dados, deve ser realizada através de webservices. Pois poderão ser banco de dados diferentes.

**Minha duvida não é sobre ferramentas, mais sim sobre uma modelagem que me entregue uma estrutura onde eu possa obter os registros que devo enviar para a outra base de dados, com o minimo de redundância possível.**

> Aceito sugestões para utilizar o banco de dados externo em estrutura não relacional (NoSQL).

Comment: Esta é uma situação temporária?

Comment: @Dherik, não é temporária, o banco de dados do aplicativo externo seria algo que ficaria na nuvem para ser consumido por outro webservice. E de tempos em tempos, os dados seriam sincronizados.

Comment: Você quer replicar apenas as alterações das tabelas ou também quer os dados delas?

Comment: @Dherik, os dados, e depois sincronizar apenas as alterações.

Comment: Certo, apenas dados. A sincronia esperada é a cada minuto, hora ou por dia?

Comment: @Dherik, o tempo entre cada sincronização, não seria relevante, mas como exemplo poderia ser considerado de hora em hora.